# cordova-plugin-filepath: unable to resolve URI as file path

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, filepath

After picking a video file from my devices filesystem via **cordova-plugin-camera**s method `navigator.camera.getPicture()`, the function returns an URI like `'content://media/external/video/media/7319'` (android).

This has to be converted into a file path for file upload via **cordova-plugin-file-transfers** function '`upload()`' (which accepts only native paths or data:URI). data:URI is no option as we have to transfer rather big files (5MB+) which converting into base64 takes way too long.

According to the developer, there is a very recent [issue](https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath/issues/3) which prevents the resolve operation.

Are there any other methods which will work on both android/ios? Or do I have to abandon cordova-plugin-file-transfer for another upload method?

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera ?
This plugin have an option to return the file path, which can be used to easily transfer the file to the server. and btw are you using ionic framework ? if so try using this plugin http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/capture/ its documented too !

Comment: @404 thank you for your comment, but cordova-plugin-camera is the plugin which I am using right now (should have mentioned this). 

Yes I'm using ionic but ngCordova/../capture does not provide a method for loading files from the devices storage. According to the docs, it can only record new files from the camera.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but you can use [**cordova-plugin-file**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file) instead of **cordova-plugin-filepath** as suggested in the [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html#take-a-picture-and-get-a-fileentry-object-):

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function cameraSuccess(imgUri) {
    uploadPicture(imgUri);
}, function cameraError(error) {
    console.debug("Unable to obtain picture: " + error, "app");
});

function uploadPicture(imgUri) {
    var uploadUrl = ...;
    var success = ...;
    var fail = ...;
    var options = ...;

    var fileEntry = getFileEntry(imgUri);
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    fileTransfer.upload(fileEntry.toURL(), encodeURI(uploadUrl), success, fail, options);
}

function getFileEntry(imgUri) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imgUri, function success(fileEntry) {
        return fileEntry;
    }, function () {
      // If don't get the FileEntry (which may happen when testing
      // on some emulators), copy to a new FileEntry.
        return createNewFileEntry(imgUri);
    });
}

function createNewFileEntry(imgUri) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, function success(dirEntry) {
        // JPEG file
        dirEntry.getFile("tempFile.jpeg", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
        return fileEntry;
    }, onErrorCreateFile);
}, onErrorResolveUrl);
```

}

Note: Not tested...